# Using jquery to load nivo slider on click inside Div?

Tags: jquery, onclick, load, nivo-slider

I am trying to load nivo slider inside a div using jQuery:

```
<a onclick='$("#content").load("slider/slider.html");'>Slider</a>
```

But that doesn't work, if I use  this script though, it works fine:

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
$("#content").load("slider/slider.html");
});
</script>
```

Any idea why it doesn't load when applied on onclick?

EDIT: Here's the jsfiddle but there the onclick doesn't work at all for me: [jsfiddle.net/ZNUY6](http://jsfiddle.net/ZNUY6)

Comment: must be your initialization code in `$(document).ready...` must be after include of html

Comment: I don't think the code is problematic, any other html loads fine, only happens on this specific slider(nothing appears when link is clicked), any other ideas?

Comment: can you share the fiddle

Comment: you're missing the closing quote

Comment: Sorry, that was a paste error, on my code I already have the closing quote. First post edited

Comment: Here's the jsfiddle but there the onclick doesn't work at all for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ZNUY6/

Answer (score 2):

You need to load data like this :

```
<a onclick='javascript:$("#content").load("slider/slider.html");'>Slider</a>
```

Thanks hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

A "more jQuery" way is to give your `a` element a class and target the slider URL:

```
<a class="ajax" href="slider/slider.html">Slider</a>
```

Then in your document.ready you set up the event handler, which loads the content:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ajax').click(function() {
        $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
        return false;
    });
});
```

The `return false` stops the link from executing its default behaviour (i.e. following the link).

This same class could be applied to many links, and with the code above, they would each load their content (per their `href` attribute) into the #content element when clicked.

An advantage of this is that you are giving your link a proper URL href, which will still work in some way even without javascript, which might be important if the content needs to be indexed by search engines, etc.

Comment: I already tried this, and even with e.preventdefault(); but nothing appears. Is there anything else I can do? Basically my index.html contains this slider, so I have to link but to the main html on the nav links, but even if I use index.html as the link it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I used a different slider and now it works so I suppose there is some compatibility issue or code matter that doesn't let nivo slider re-load when using this method.